# list.files with folder name and folder files included in output r

Tags: r, string, list

If have a folder (My_Data) with 2 subfolders (Wood, Soil) for instance.

My desired output is a list of the form;

$Wood

[1] "bamboo.pdf"

$Soil

[1] "loamy.xls" "clay.xls"

I have the following code so far.

list.files(path = "myfile_path/My_Data", recursive = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) %>% basename()

I've used the list.files() function but my output is a merged list of all files present in the subfolders.
How do I present my output in the desired format referenced above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This gets close I think?

```
sapply(list.dirs('myfile_path/My_Data'), 
       list.files)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Quite close but I still need to tidy it a bit. Looks like the next step now is to only replace the displayed folder path in the output with the folder name

Comment: names(result) <- list.dirs('myfile_path/My_Data', 
                            full.names = F)

Comment: The previous coded you provided actually worked better. The most recent code only returns the Main folder contents and directories.  I'm trying to explore alternative ways of modifying the output.